# Detecting Multiple subfolders within the main folder using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

UPDATED:

Hi. Apologies if my question sounds vague. When I run both Scripts below together all the csv files from ES and LTC sub-folder end up in one folder instead of two folders. I have two separate scripts 
to monitor two sub-folders LTC and ES and copy the files to the folders.

LTC Script:

```
 $folder = 'C:\2014-15'
 $destination = 'N:\Test'

 $fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $true
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName'
}

 $created = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {
 $item = Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
 If ($item.Name -ilike "LTC") {

  Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination $destination
 }
}

  $renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Renamed -Action {
  $item = Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
  If ($item.Name -ilike "LTC") {

  Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination $destination 
 }
}
```

ES Script:

```
    $folder = 'C:\2014-15'
    $destination = 'N:\Test1'

  $fsw = New-Object  System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder  -Property @{

  IncludeSubdirectories = $true

  NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName'

 }

  $created = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {

  $item =  Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath

  If ($item.Name -ilike "ES") {

  Copy-Item "$item\*.csv" -Destination $destination

  }

 }
  $created = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {

  $item =  Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath

  If ($item.Name -ilike "ES") {

  Copy-Item "$item\*.csv" -Destination $destination

   }

 }
```

Comment: Change the `$destination` to `"$destination\ES"`?

Comment: @arco44 that's didn't work.

Comment: Are these scripts, or just commands that you ran in ISE?

Comment: I don't think we understand your problem. Are your watch actions not working properly or a specific one? Is this just a matter of having a second copy destination. Is the LTC code putting files in the wrong directory? Are these defined in the same file? So is $destination not taking the change?

Comment: @Matt. Apologies if my question sounds vague. When I run both Scripts together all the csv files from ES and LTC subfolder end up in Test1 folder when it should be LTC in Test and ES in Test1 folder.

Comment: Must have something to do with the watchers not melding well together. Could these just not be merged into the same watcher with `switch`

Comment: I thought of that but not sure the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $folder = 'C:\2014-15'
 $destination = 'N:\Test'
 $destination1 = 'N:\Test1'

 $fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $true
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName'
}

 $created = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {
 $item = Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
 If ($item.Name -ilike "LTC") {

  Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination $destination
 }
}

  $renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Renamed -Action {
  $item = Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
  If ($item.Name -ilike "LTC") {

  Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination $destination 
 }
}


  $fsw = New-Object  System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder  -Property @{

  IncludeSubdirectories = $true

  NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'DirectoryName'

 }

  $created = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {

  $item1 =  Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath

  If ($item1.Name -ilike "ES") {

  Copy-Item "$item1\*.csv" -Destination $destination1

  }

 }
  $created = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw -EventName Created -Action {

  $item1 =  Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath

  If ($item1.Name -ilike "ES") {

  Copy-Item "$item1\*.csv" -Destination $destination1

   }

 }
```